# Cant run response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, submit

I have a form and I'm using `jquery.ajax` to run the `PHP` code in the background. The problem is that when I receive the response from the script, my `Javascript` code doesn't handle it very well.

If I use *`if (status == "success")`* it works (but it's not the right way to handle this operation), but if I use *`if (response == "allok")`*, it doesn't work and the submit form stops working. `(no messages in Console)`

With an `alert` or `echo`, I can see the right value of "`response`", but for some reason, if I use this value in the `if`, the entire `script` stops running. Why is that?

HTML code:

```html
<form id="form" class="registrazione" action="ajax/verifica.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="username" placeholder="Nome utente..." autocomplete="off" autofocus>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="email" placeholder="Email..." autocomplete="off">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="password" placeholder="Password..." autocomplete="off">
    <input type="password" id="conferma_password" name="conferma_password" class="password" placeholder="Riscrivi la password..." autocomplete="off">
    <p id="risultato"></p>
    <input type="submit" id="form_button" name="form_button" class="form_button" value="Continua">
</form>
```

JS code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#form").submit(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var username=$("#username").val();
    var email=$("#email").val();
    var password=$("#password").val();
    var conferma_password=$("#conferma_password").val();
    var submit=$("#form_button").val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "ajax/verifica.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        username: username,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        conferma_password: conferma_password,
        submit: submit
      },
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(response,status){
        if (response == "allok") {
          $("#risultato").html('Risposta='+risposta+' Status='+status);
          // alert('Account creato!');
        }
        if (status == "error") {
          alert("Ops! Si è verificato un errore interno momentaneo. Riprova più tardi, grazie.");
        }
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Ops! Generic error.");
      }      
    })

  })

});
```

PHP code:

```php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $username=$_POST['username'];
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $conferma_password=$_POST['conferma_password'];

  $errorMessage=false;
  $errorUsername=false;
  $errorEmail=false;
  $errorPassword=false;
  $errorConfermaPassword=false;

  $username_regex="/^[a-z0-9._-]{2,35}$/i";
  $password_regex="/^(?=.*\d.*\d)[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%*]{8,}$/";

  if (empty($username)) {
    echo "Write a username.";
    $errorUsername=true;
    $errorMessage=true;
  }

  if (empty($email)) {
    echo "Write a email.";
    $errorEmail=true;
    $errorMessage=true;
  }

  if (empty($password)) {
    echo "Write a password.";
    $errorPassword=true;
    $errorMessage=true;
  }

  if (empty($conferma_password)) {
    echo "Password check again.";
    $errorConfermaPassword=true;
    $errorMessage=true;
  }

  if ($password!=$conferma_password) {
    echo "Password check.";
    $errorPassword=true;
    $errorMessage=true;
  }

  if (!preg_match($username_regex, $username)) {
    echo "Not a valid username.";
    $errorUsername=true;
    $errorMessage=true;
  }

  if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "Not a valid email address.";
    $errorEmail=true;
    $errorMessage=true;
  }

  if (!preg_match($password_regex, $password)) {
    echo "Not a valid password.";
    $errorPassword=true;
    $errorMessage=true;
  }

  $query="SELECT id,nome,cognome FROM test WHERE username='$username'";
  $result=mysqli_query($connessione, $query);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "Username not available.";
    $errorUsername=true;
    $errorMessage=true;
  }

  if ($errorMessage==false) {
    echo "allok";
  }

}
else {
  echo "Generic error.";
}
```

Comment: I already used dataType with json, html, text also but it doesn't work.

Comment: How does the response look like. Maybe you can check what is actually in response. Ergo, console.log(response).

Comment: There's no obvious problem with the code you've shown, but I'd guess that there is whitespace around the output (which is why encoding the output as JSON and then parsing it on the client is a good approach: Aside from allowing more complex data structures, it normalises whitespace).

Comment: Side note: in your success handler you name the receiving parameter `response`, but then you try to use `risposta` inside `.html()`.

Comment: @El_Vanja you are right. Publishing this post, I simply forgot to translate "risposta" into "response".

Comment: @M1sterPl0w you did it! In effect the response string is full of javascript code that I accidentally inserted at the end of the PHP file and this caused the error in the entire page. Thank you!

Comment: @Marc nice! Glad this helped. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're simply echo-ing out a string to your AJAX script.
It is receiving one of the following strings:

- Write a username
- Write a email
- Write a password
- (etc for all of your echo's)

These will all direct back to the success handler of your AJAX script, but in that handler you're expecting two parameters. These will be filled by whatever you echo back from your PHP script, in your case one of the above.

Furthermore, the second parameter in this case is 'status', which is supposedly always 'success' if the AJAX call is led towards the 'success' handler. Your if-statement concerning 'error' in your 'success' handler will therefore never be reached.

You might want to try the following in your PHP file:

```
$response = new StdClass;
$response->status = 'success';
$response->message = <any of the above statements>;

$response = json_encode($response);

echo $response;
```

Then in your AJAX script you can use the following:

```
success: function(response){

              if (response.status == "allok") {
              $("#risultato").html('Risposta='+risposta+' Status='+status);
              //alert('Account creato!');
              }
              if (response.status == "error") {
              alert("Ops! Si è verificato un errore interno momentaneo. Riprova più tardi, grazie.");
              }
```

Furthermore, I discourage the use of any other language in your code besides English. Mixing up italian and english variable names makes your code harder to read. I come across this a lot in code written by less experienced programmers.

Comment: _"...but in that handler you're expecting two parameters. These will be filled in order of the echo-ed response..."_ - I don't follow. `status` is filled by AJAX automatically and it's a string representation of the AJAX status. It won't be filled with any information returned by the script.

Comment: @El_Vanja You are correct, my bad. I will change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, there was a JS code inside the PHP file which was automatically included inside the response string. So this was the problem. I fixed it removing the JS code and publishing it in the right place (in the HTML code for example).